# How we can wait a Kafka message from another topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Imagine that an order is created in an e-commerce application, and shipments of the order are created as soon as the order is placed. Here, we have considered two Events for Kafka, one is the OrderCreatedEvent at the time the order is created and the other is the ShippingCreatedEvent. When the OrderCreatedEvent occurs, a message is sent to Kafka, then the shipments are created and the ShippingCreatedEvent is sent. Here, when the Consumer application first learns that the shipments have occurred, it throws an error because it does not have an Order yet. The consumer who processes the shipments here must first process the Order of that shipment. Do you have any idea about how we can handle this kinda situation without using retry mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite typical.

Events with the same event key (e.g., your order id) are written to the same partition, and Kafka guarantees that any consumer of a given topic-partition will always read that partition's events in exactly the same order as they were written.

And Kafka guarantees any partition will be consumed by only one consumer of any consumer group.

And you can custom your own partitioner.

see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_partitioner.class

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I planned to use 2 different topics and 2 different topic keys. I have many of events and all of them will use these two by occuring event.

Answer (score 0):

You need an "order fulfillment" consumer process that reads the `OrderCreatedEvent` to initiate "gathering materials" and "starting the shipment". Then write a new producer to send `ShippingCreatedEvent` message.

> throws an error because it does not have an Order yet

You should clarify this. Kafka doesn't care about existence of data or not. That would be your custom logic in your code throwing errors. If you've started a shipment from the "`OrderCreatedEvent` topic consumer", then you **do** have an Order.

If you needed to join orderId with shipmentId for tracking end-to-end supply-chain / deliveries, for example, then you can start to use KTables and other databases for storing asset statuses.